# Form is not submitting in jQuery ajax success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am making a simple form of single text input.I want to cross check from db that is it exist or not.So my html is

```
<form action="zoneAdd" method="post"  id="zoneAdd" name="zoneAdd">
            <div class="box-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Zone Name<span id="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="zone_name" id="zone_name" placeholder="Enter Zone Name" />
                    <span id="zone_name_error"></span>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.box-body -->
            <div class="box-footer">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat btn-sm" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </div>
        </form>
```

and my javasript is

```
 $('document').ready(function(){
    $("[name=submit]").click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
        if ($('#zone_name').val().length <= 0) {
            $('#zone_name').addClass("errMsg");
            $('#zone_name_error').addClass("errMsgDngr");
            $('#zone_name_error').html('Please enter Zone name!');
            //isStepValid = false;
        }
        else if(!$('#zone_name').val().match(/^[a-zA-Z\s-, ]+$/)){
            $('#zone_name').addClass("errMsg");
            $('#zone_name_error').addClass("errMsgDngr");
            $('#zone_name_error').html('Please use only alphabats!');
            //isStepValid = false;
        }else{
            var data = {'zone':$('#zone_name').val()}
            $.ajax({
                type:"post",
                data:data,
                url:"<?php echo site_url('zone/checkZoneName');?>",
                success:function(err){
                    if(err == 0)
                    {
                        console.log('hello');
                        $('#zone_name_error').html('');
                        $('#zone_name_error').removeClass("errMsg");
                        $('#zone_name_error').removeClass("errMsgDngr");
                        //document.forms["zoneAdd"].submit();
                        $('form#zoneAdd').submit();
                        //console.log($('form#zoneAdd').submit());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#zone_name').addClass("errMsg");
                        $('#zone_name_error').addClass("errMsgDngr");
                        $('#zone_name_error').html('Zone Name already existed!');
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    });
});
```

every thing is going right. My problem is my form is not submit in ajax success

Comment: @DhavalMarthak - there's a `preventDefault`, twice, that avoids that issue.

Comment: It seems to send the request just fine for me, you're sure it's not the response that is the issue ?

Comment: May be you want to add semicolon(;) in line just before AJAX call.

Comment: button is not working, i am getiing hello in console and if i do document.forms["zoneAdd"].submit(); it is giving document is not a function error.

Comment: The problem is in your var data. Make it simple in AJAX call.

Comment: ajax is working fine, means console.log(err) giving expected result;

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in form action.
Specify exact path in the form action such that

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('filenameWhereyouSubmit')?>"        method="post"  id="zoneAdd" name="zoneAdd">
```

Answer (score 0):

Start form like this :

```
  <form id="FORM-ID" method="post" action="">
```

For ajax submit

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     $('#FORM-ID').submit(function(e) {

        var myarray=  array of all form values
        var data = JSON.stringify(myarray);

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {value:data},
        url: "URL TO SUBMIT",
        success: function() {
             //Sucess function 
        }

    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't have a handler function on form submit and your ajax call
   happens after `$("[name=submit]").click()`.
2. You're submitting the form after ajax success:

   ```
   success:function(err){
           if(err == 0)
               {
                  ...
                  $('form#zoneAdd').submit();
                  ...
               }

      }
   ```
3. but the submit is not ajax call, so try to handle the form
   `onsubmit`.

something like this:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('form#zoneAdd').submit(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();

         // You checks code ...

         var data = {
               'zone': $('#zone_name').val()
             };

         $.ajax({

                type:"post",
                data:data,
                url:"<?php echo site_url('zone/checkZoneName');?>",
                success: function (err){

                    if(err == 0)
                    {
                        console.log('hello');
                        $('#zone_name_error').html('');
                        $('#zone_name_error').removeClass("errMsg");
                        $('#zone_name_error').removeClass("errMsgDngr");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#zone_name').addClass("errMsg");
                        $('#zone_name_error').addClass("errMsgDngr");
                        $('#zone_name_error').html('Zone Name already existed!');
                    }

                }
         });


    });
});
```

Comment: $("form#submit") not initialising

Comment: when you pressing `type="submit"` buttom?

Comment: simply when i want to submit the form