# jQuery ajax - validate with ajax and if no error, submit form and redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Note: I don't want to submit with ajax, but to validate with ajax, and then, if success, submit it. But it is not working.

I have a HTML form with `action` of some Django url. Now, to validate it at web side and then at server side, I do this:

- jQuery.`validate()` the form, if valid, enable the button with id `submit`. This button has no `name=` attribute.
- The button is a plain button `type="button"`. I click it to `ajax` the form data(`$('#formManager').serialize()`), to an URL named `verifyScript` to do server side verification. This function returns Django `JSONResponse` as result.
- In the `success: function(returned, status, xhr){}` handler, I want to submit the form with `$('#formManager').submit()`; in this action I do a redirection to other pages. But the form is not submitted. The JS code is executed, but nothing happens and no redirection. `async` is set to `false`.

My template form:

```
<form role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="formManager" onsubmit="activate(this)" action=
    {% if action == "edit" %} 
        "{% url 'modifyScript' %}"
    {% elif action == "create" or action == "copy" %}
        "{% url 'createScript' %}"
    {% endif %}
>
...
<button type="button" id="submit"  class="btn btn-success">
    {% if action == 'edit' %}
        Edit Script
    {% elif action == 'create' %}
        Create Script
    {% elif action == 'copy' %}
        Copy Script
    {% endif %}
</button>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
....

/* remove the "disabled" attribute when we submit the form when editing */
function activate(form) {
    $(form).find("select").each(function(i, e) {
        if ($(e).disabled == true) {
            $(e).prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });
    var input = $(form).find("#machine");
    if (input.prop("disabled") == true) {
        input.prop("disabled", false);
    }
}

$('#submit').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:       "POST",
        url:        "{% url 'verifyScript'%}",
        data:       $('#formManager').serialize(),
        dataType:   "json",
        async:      false,
        success:    submitForm

    })
});
});

});

function submitForm(returned, status, xhr) {
    var success = returned['success'];
    if (success) {
        $("#formManager").submit();
        return;
    } else {
        $('#verifyError').html(returned['errorMsg']);
        $('#myModalVerify').modal('show');
        return;
    }
}
```

I think it is a known issue. I have seen questions alike but none of the solutions works. For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415740/jquery-resume-form-submit-after-ajax-call) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894543/form-is-not-submitting-in-jquery-ajax-success), but they don't solve my problem.

But checking these question have inspired me to pay attention to:

- extract `success` callback to be a separated callable, without `()` and parameters;
- add `return` in said callable
- assure that there is no elements with `name="submit"` in the same page
- ensure to make the button type to be `type="button"` to prevent calling the form action before validation.

But it is still not submitted.

EDIT1:

change `async` to `false`.

I created [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/torresdyl/x1za8fq3/16/) example trying to show with real code, but the verification and submitting seem not possible(if someone can mock this please feel free to update). The main idea is a form with some disabled fields needs to be ajax-verified, and if the return result contains "success", we submit it. And, on submission, we need to activate the disabled fields before sending the data to server, so we have the `onsubmit` function.

I have figured it out: `onsubmit` should return `true` to submit the form.
, but I need some more enlightenment on this: why?

Comment: It is difficult to debug code fragments.

Comment: just to be clear, `async` IS set to `false`, right? because in your code it isn't, and in the other questions you refer to, it is

Comment: At last it does not affect... at least in this concrete case I guess. PS: why there are multiple requests? And after reading the doc, I still cannot get it clear how this option affects the POST process.

Comment: Added jsfiddle as showcase, although the submission part does not work... feel free to collaborate. Question updated, too.